# Clearest way to declare a char value containing a single quote/apostrophe

Tags: c#, char

To declare a char value in C# we just surround the character with single quotes: `'x'`.

But what is the "clearest" way to declare a char value that *is* a single quote/apostrophe?

I've ended up using `"'"[0]`, though I had expected `''''` to work (on the basis that `""` can be used to delimit a quote character within a string.

Is there a sensible, more succinct option?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can escape the quote with a backslash: `'\''`

Answer (score 15):

You can also use  `'\''` or `(char)39`

Comment: How can we use (char)39 inside a char variable. I tried to put it within the single quotes, but it didn't recognize it.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're looking for `'\''`

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's a matter of personal preference, I find escaping it clearest, eg:

```
char c = '\'';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always just try:

```
 char c = '\'';
```

Answer (score 2):

For a char I would use

```
myChar = '\'';
```

The backslash is the standard escape key in both strings and characters, and most people should be able to understand this just fine.