# How to express the ' character as a character literal

Tags: c#, char, character, syntax-error, literals

So I want an array of char object similar to this:

```
        char[] allowedCharactersUnreserved = new char[] {
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 
            'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', '_', '.' 
        };
```

Problem is saving the: ' element

```
        char[] allowedCharactersReserved = new char[] {
           '#', '[', ']', ''' <---- problem
        };
```

I get an "empty character literal" error

Comment: This question can be reduced to: "How to express the ' character as a character literal". It has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clearest way to declare a char value containing a single quote/apostrophe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818231/clearest-way-to-declare-a-char-value-containing-a-single-quote-apostrophe)

Comment: Ganjan, C, C++, Java, C#  use this `'\''` convention

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to escape the `'` character with the `\` character: `'\''`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it using a backslash: `'\''`. It's the same as you would do to escape `"` in a string: `"\""`.

Answer (score 2):

its better to use

```
char[] allowedCharactersUnreserved = 
       @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabc'[]""#".ToCharArray(); //where ("") char is (")
```