# Equals() method not recognizing similar/same characters when comparing

Tags: c#, comparison, equals

Why comparing characters with `.Equals` always returns false?

```
char letter = 'a';
Console.WriteLine(letter.Equals("a")); // false
```

Overall I'm trying to write an English - Morse Code translator. I run into a problem comparing char values which shown above. I began with a `foreach` to analyze all the characters from a `ReadLine()` input, by using the `WriteLine()` method, all the characters were transposed fine, but when trying to compare them using the .Equals() method, no matter what I did, it always output false when trying to compare chars.

I have used the `.Equals()` method with other strings successfully, but it seems to not work with my chars.

```
using System;
public class MorseCode {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Hello, write anything to convert it to morse code!");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    foreach (char letter in input) {
      if(letter.Equals("a")) {
        Console.WriteLine("Its A - live");
      }
      Console.WriteLine(letter);
    }
    var morseTranslation = "";
    foreach (char letter in input) {
      if(letter.Equals("a")) {
       morseTranslation += ". _ - ";
      }
      if(letter.Equals("b")) {
       morseTranslation += "_ . . . - ";
      }
      if(letter.Equals("c")) {
       morseTranslation += "_ . _ . - ";
      }
      ...
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("In morse code, " + input + " is '"morseTranslation + "'");
  }
}
```

At the beginning, I wrote the `foreach` to test if it recognized and ran the correct output, but in the end, when I wrote "sample" into the `ReadLine()`, it gave me :

```
Hello, write anything to convert it to morse code!
sample
s
a
m
p
l
e
```

Comment: Additionally to what @SerhatOz wrote in their answer, why would you want to use `letter.Equals('a')` instead of `letter == 'a'` (which conveniently would also not allow you to accidentally compare a character with a string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to remember that whilst the [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char) and [string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) keywords look reminiscant of eachother when looking at printed values you should note that they are not accomodated for in exactly the same way.

When you check a string you can use:

```
string s = "A";
if(s.Equals("A"))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

However, the above will not work with a `char`. The [difference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88c3ab19-b85d-4c61-9cfa-a487c8be8767/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes?forum=csharpgeneral) between [chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818231/clearest-way-to-declare-a-char-value-containing-a-single-quote-apostrophe) ([value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)) and strings ([reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)) on a surface level is the use of access - single quote (apostrophe) vs quote.

To compare a `char` you can do this:

```
char s = 'A';
if(s.Equals('A'))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

On a point relevant to your specific case however, morse code will only requre you to use a single case alphabet and as such when you try to compare against `'A'` and `'a'` you can call `input.ToLower()` to reduce your `var` (string) to all lower case so you don't need to cater for both upper and lower case alphabets.

It's good that you're aware of string comparissons and are not using [direct value comparisson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons) as this:

```
if (letter == 'a')
{
    Console.WriteLine("Its A - live");
}
```

Would've allowed you to compare the char but it's bad practice as it may lead to lazy comparisson of strings in the same way and this:

```
if (letter == "a")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Its A - live");
}
```

Is a non-representitive method of comparison for the purpose of comparing strings as it evaluates the reference not the direct value, see [here](https://coding.abel.nu/2014/09/net-and-equals/)

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
var c = 'x';
var isEqual = c.Equals("x");
```

the result (`isEqual`) will always be false because it's comparing a `string` to a `char`. This would return true:

```
var isEqual = c.Equals('x');
```

The difference is that `"x"` is a `string` literal and `'x'` is a `char` literal.

Part of what makes this confusing is that when you use an object's `Equals` method, it allows you to compare any type to any other type. So you could do this:

```
var x = 0;
var y = "y";
var isEqual = x.Equals(y);
```

...and the compiler will allow it, even though the comparison between `int` and `string` won't work. It will give you this warning:

When comparing value types like `int` or `char` with other values of the same type, we usually use `==`, like

```
if (someChar == someOtherChar)
```

Then if you tried to do this:

```
if(someChar == "a")
```

It wouldn't compile. It would tell you that you're comparing a `char` to a `string`, and then it's easier because instead of running the program and looking for the error it just won't compile at all and it will tell you exactly where the problem is.

---

Just for the fun of it, here's another implementation.

```
public static class MorseCodeConverter
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<char, string> Codes 
        = CreateMorseCodeDictionary();

    public static string Convert(string input)
    {
        var lowerCase = input.ToLower();
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var character in input)
        {
            if (Codes.ContainsKey(character))
                result.Append(Codes[character]);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }

    static Dictionary<char, string> CreateMorseCodeDictionary()
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<char, string>();
        result.Add('a', ". _ - ");
        result.Add('b', "_ . . . - ");
        // add all the rest
        return result;
    }
}
```

One difference is that it's a class by itself without the console app. Then you can use it in a console app. Read the input from the keyboard and then call

```
MorseCodeConverter.Convert(input);
```

to get the result, and then you can print it to the console.a

Putting all of the characters in a dictionary means that instead of repeating the `if/then` you can just check to see if each character is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

For char comparison you have to use single quote ' character not " this.
By the way it writes sample in decending order beacuse in your first foreach loop you write all letters in new line. SO below code will work for you:

```
using System;
public class MorseCode {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Hello, write anything to convert it to morse code!");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    /*foreach (char letter in input) {
      if(letter.Equals("a")) {
        Console.WriteLine("Its A - live");
      }
      Console.WriteLine(letter);
    }*/
    var morseTranslation = "";
    foreach (char letter in input) {
      if(letter.Equals('a')) {
       morseTranslation += ". _ - ";
      }
      if(letter.Equals('b')) {
       morseTranslation += "_ . . . - ";
      }
      if(letter.Equals('c')) {
       morseTranslation += "_ . _ . - ";
      }
      ...
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("In morse code, " + input + " is '"morseTranslation + "'");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you *can* compare strings like integers, that is with `==` operator. `Equals` is a method inherited from the `object` class, and normally implementations would make some type checks. `char letter` is (obviously) a character, while `"a"` is a single lettered `string`.

That's why it returns `false`.

You could use `if (letter.Equals('a')) { ... }`, or simpler `if (letter == 'a') { ... }`

Even simpler than that would be `switch (letter) { case 'a': ...; break; ... }`.

Or something that is more elegant but maybe too advanced yet for a beginner, using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq):

```cs
var validCharacters = "ABCDE...";
var codes = new string[] {
".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", ...
};
var codes = input.ToUpper() // make uppercase
  .ToCharArray() // explode string into single characters
  .Select(validCharaters.IndexOf) // foreach element (i. e. character), get the result of "validCharacters.IndexOf",
                                  // which equals the index of the morse code in the array "codes"
  .Where(i => i > -1) // only take the indexes of characters that were found in "validCharacters"
  .Select(i => codes[i]); // retrieve the matching entry from "codes" by index

// "codes" is now an IEnumerable<string>, a structure saying
// "I am a list of strings over which you can iterate,
//  and I know how to generate the elements as you request them."
// Now concatenate all single codes to one long result string
var result = string.Join(" ", codes);
```